# $\mathcal{G}$-measurable RV's are $T$-invariant - extending result from generators of $\sigma$-algebra to whole $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, ergodic-theory

Context: [these](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~mrasmuss/ergodictheory/ErgodicTheoryNotes.pdf) lecture notes, exercise 47. Not a homework assignment.

> $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is a probability space, $T:X\rightarrow X$ is a probability preserving map. 
>   Define $$\mathcal{G}:= \sigma (\{A\in \mathcal{F}:T^{-1}(A)=A\}).$$
>   Prove that $\mathcal{G}$-measurable RV's are $T$-invariant (i.e. $f\circ T = f,$ $\mu$ almost everywhere).

My attempt:
$$T^{-1}(A) = A \implies A = T(A)$$
$$\implies f(T(A)) = f(A).$$

So when restricted to the generators of $\mathcal{G}$, $f\circ T=f$. How can I extend this to the whole $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Please check my editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we have
$$
\mathcal G=\{A\in\mathcal F:T^{-1}A=A\}.
$$
If you prefer: the collection of all measurable $T$-invariant sets is a $\sigma$-algebra (simply verify the axioms). Because of this, you have in fact already considered all sets in $\mathcal G$.

*PS: One can show that $f$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable if and only if it is $T$ invariant almost everywhere.*

Comment: Oh ok, so that collection of sets is already a $\sigma$-algebra, hence I've already checked it for the whole $\sigma$-algebra